# Make nl to enumerate from a specified line

Tags: bash

I intent to enumerate the files and dirs

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z /]# ls -lh |nl
     1  total 60K
     2  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 15 22:08 bin -> usr/bin
     3  dr-xr-xr-x.  5 root root 4.0K Jun 15 22:10 boot
     4  drwxr-xr-x  19 root root 2.9K Sep 17 11:35 dev
     5  drwxr-xr-x. 85 root root 4.0K Sep 18 22:44 etc
     6  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Sep 17 08:25 home
     7  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 15 22:08 lib -> usr/lib
     8  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jun 15 22:08 lib64 -> usr/lib64
     9  drwx------.  2 root root  16K Oct 15  2017 lost+found
    10  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Apr 11  2018 media
    11  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Apr 11  2018 mnt
    12  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Apr 11  2018 opt
    13  dr-xr-xr-x  86 root root    0 Sep 17 11:35 proc
    14  drwxrwxrwx. 21 root root 4.0K Oct 22 08:11 root
    15  drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  660 Oct 24 19:10 run
    16  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Jun 15 22:08 sbin -> usr/sbin
    17  drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4.0K Apr 11  2018 srv
    18  dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Oct 21 19:50 sys
    19  drwxrwxrwt. 11 root root 4.0K Oct 24 05:19 tmp
    20  drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4.0K Jun 15 22:08 usr
    21  drwxr-xr-x. 19 root root 4.0K Jun 15 22:08 var
```

It starts with 1 which I desire is 0.

How could make `nl` to enumerate from a specified line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the -v option, and specify to start from 0; your instruction becoming:

```
ls -lh |nl -v 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets have a look at `nl --help`:

```
$ nl --help
Usage: nl [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Write each FILE to standard output, with line numbers added.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
...
  -v, --starting-line-number=NUMBER  first line number for each section
```

Therefore:

```
$ nl -v0 <<EOF
> a
> b
> EOF
     0  a
     1  b
```

Note that it does not really matter whether you want to enumerate directories or anything else, which is why you probably should strip this part from your question to make it more specific.